# Html Link HREF doesn't resolve until element is inspected

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to make a script to include in a Minimalist Chrome Extension module. The first cut will, on load, find all links on a page, find which links include a blacklisted website name, and then remove itself.

If I query a page that contains a number of clickbait links, I find that the hrefs change upon inspection. If I query all `<a>`'s, the links in question will show an href that doesn't include the clickbait domain. If I right-click and inspect, then query again, all of the sudden they are there.

What the heck is going on and how can I catch it? CNN articles and Gizmodo articles have links that behave in this way.

Comment: Can you please share some code so that others have chance to try and reproduce the behavior you describe?

Comment: it's very simple to add or change href only when event occurs. Sounds like that is what you are running into. Or you are checking before dynamic content has been inserted. Without any code shown not much anyone can do to help

Comment: var t = document.getElementsByTagName('a');var x = []; for(var i = 0; i< t.length; i++){if(t[i].href.indexOf('outbrain.com')!== -1){x.push(t[i].href);}};x

Comment: If you run that in the console on a CNN article (where all of their clickbait comes from Outbrain), save the output array somewhere as a baseline. Now right-click and inspect a clickbait link. Now run the same snippet again and you'll see the href's change.

Comment: provide example CNN link

Comment: http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/13/investing/wells-fargo-scandal-stock-jpmorgan/index.html

Comment: gazzilion links on that page...where are offenders? Anyway, they very likely change the href when an event occurs based on your description

Comment: The links change on every page load. Look toward the bottom. Anything under a blue header that says "Paid Content" is fair game and will have an Outbrain domain in it's link.

Comment: can clearly see it in the live html .... `onmousedown="this.href=....`

Answer (score 1):

Based on link provided in comments above, the href's are changed in other event handlers.

One example from the cnn page looks a bit like:

```
<a onmousedown="this.href='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?p=Mq...."
```

You could try parsing the element attributes to look for the blacklisted domains.

Reference [MDN Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)